# Robots.txt block all except Google and partners

Tags: joomla3.0, robots.txt

I am trying to block all bots from my site and allow only Google and its partners to have access (except one folder).

This is my robots.txt

However, I see from my log that twitterbot is able to access my site

```
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 560 "-" "Twitterbot/1.0"
```

Here is my txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /


User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-news
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: AdsBot-Google
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: AdsBot-Google-Mobile
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: APIs-Google
Disallow: /administrator
Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: As per with your robots.txt you only disallow to google related partners can you please allow add twitter in your list and check

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:-

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
Allow: /tr/
Allow: /istanbul*
Allow: /ankara*
Allow: /izmir*
Allow: /çeşme*
Allow: /bursa*
Allow: /adana*
Allow: /antalya*
Allow: /izmit*
Allow: /konya*
Allow: /gaziantep*
Allow: /bodrum*
Allow: /eskisehir*
Allow: /bozcaada*

User-agent: SeznamBot
Sitemap: https://www.zomato.com/sitemap_seznam.xml.gz
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: DuckDuckBot
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /clients/
Disallow: /voicephp/
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /pt/
Disallow: /tr/
Disallow: /pl/
Disallow: /id/
Disallow: /cs/
Disallow: /sk/
Disallow: /vi/
Disallow: /it/
Disallow: /es/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /mydashboard
Allow: /

User-agent: AhrefsBot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: Applebot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: SearchmetricsBot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: SEMrushBot
Disallow: /downloads/
Disallow: /nonsvn/
Disallow: /webview/
Disallow: /*/tag-*
Disallow: /*?*q=
Disallow: /*?*%2525*
Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: So I should add "Allow: /" in every user agent? Also, I have the last entry disallow to all. But twitter bot has a 200

Comment: Please try with this approach and let me know if issue exists.:)

Comment: I use this approach, as I have already the last entry for * user agent. But twitterbot still have access

Comment: So just use ```Disallow: /``` in ```Twitterbot```